# How to efficiently apply combinations to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I have been working for while with a function that takes a certain df, and it applys a combinatory operation on it. Basically, it takes one column, and it create all the posible pairs between the values in that column while copying also the info in each pair.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':["A","B","C"],"int":[0,1,2],"str":["a","b","c"]})
+-------+------+-----+
| names |  int | str |
+-------+------+-----+
| A     |    0 | "a" |
| B     |    1 | "b" |
| C     |    2 | "C" |
+-------+------+-----+
```

And it transforms it into another df with this form:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
| names1 | names2 | ints1 | ints2 | str1 | str2 |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
| A      | B      |     0 |     1 | "a"  | "b"  |
| A      | C      |     0 |     2 | "a"  | "c"  |
| B      | C      |     1 |     2 | "b"  | "c"  |
+--------+--------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

This is the same operation as the function [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from itertools does.
I have written a function that works well when using small databases(<20MB) but I when apply the same function to dbs of 100 MB, it can take severals days to accomplish this operation due to use of [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).
**My question is** how can I speed up this by using other methods like apply, or np.vectorize.

The function that does this with iterrows is this one:

```py
def combinatory(data):
    # combines each name with another pair with no repetition
    # Ej: A,B,C 
    # A B data_A data_B
    # A C data_A data_C
    # B C data_B data_C
    def createpairs(data):
        import itertools
        # creates each of the pairs
        pairs = []
        n_names = data["names"].unique().tolist()
        for n_names in itertools.combinations(n_names,2):
            pairs.append(n_names)
        pairs = pd.DataFrame(pairs)
        pairs.columns = ["name1", "name2"]
        return pairs
    
    pairs = createpairs(data)
    data_1 = data.iloc[0:0]
    data_2 = data.iloc[0:0]
    for index, row in pairs.iterrows():
        # Selecting each name inside the pairs
        tray_name1 = data_1[row['name1']]
        tray_name2 = data_2[row['name2']]
        # Getting the first row of the name of each pair
        init_values_name1 = tray_name1.iloc[0]
        init_values_name2 = tray_name2.iloc[0]
        # Putting the info inside a df
        Data_name1 = Data_name1.append(init_values_name1)
        Data_name2 = Data_name2.append(init_values_name2)
    

    Data_fil_name1.index = range(Data_name1.shape[0])
    Data_fil_name2.index = range(Data_name2.shape[0])
    

    Data_end = Data_fil_name1.join(Data_fil_name2, lsuffix= '_1', rsuffix = '_2')
    Data_end = pares.join(Data_end)

    return Data_end
```

Comment: are you tring to convert each row into new coolumn? How the output looks when data frame has 5 rows(for example)?

Comment: No, if there was for example a "C" in names with int = 2 and str= "c". It would combine them as well, like "a"| "c" |"1"| "2"| "a·"| "c" and the combination with "b". The number of columns wouldnt change in the new df.

Comment: @jaimebw can you edit your question to show this more clearly?

Comment: @mullinscr done, hope its more clear.

Comment: Can you post the current solution that you refer to as well. Thanks

Comment: Why is there not the following row in the solution: `A      | B      |     0 |     1 | "b"  | "c" `

Comment: Can you show us your functino and how you implement it?

Comment: @nick because "c" is not in the same row as B, it has to be in the same row.

Comment: @mullinscr ill edit it, need sometime to make it redaeable

Comment: @mullinscr done, hope its more clear

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? Using vectorised approach.

Input:

```
  names  int str
0     A    0   a
1     B    1   b
2     C    2   c
```

Method:

```
import itertools

df = df.astype('str') # check all are string dtypes
# concat all items together
# I used a comma but use whatever separator is best for you
df['temp'] = df['names'] + ',' + df['int'] + ',' + df['str'] 

# calculate all combinations
new = pd.DataFrame([x for x in itertools.combinations(df.temp, 2)])
# combine into a single column (again use whatever delimitor is best)
new['temp'] = new[0] + ',' + new[1]

# split them apart into new columns
output = new['temp'].str.split(',', expand=True)
# rename columns
output.columns = ['names1', 'ints1', 'string1', 'names2', 'ints2', 'string2']
```

Output:

```
  names1 ints1 string1 names2 ints2 string2
0      A     0       a      B     1       b
1      A     0       a      C     2       c
2      B     1       b      C     2       c
```

Comment: Nice try, Ill try to apply what you have done, it is a nice approach. The thing is that the data I have  is more complex than the one in the example(more columns, and different kind of dtypes).

Comment: You can always convert your data types again afterwards. And don't forget to use a non-conflicting delimiter.